# how to self change attrs in openldap

Tags: openldap, access-control-list

I am running openldap is 2.4.40 and have applied following ACL:

```
olcAccess: {0}to *      
          by self write       
          by dn="cn=Manager,dc=sample,dc=com" write       
          by * read
olcAccess: {1}to dn.children="ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com" 
           attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange,description,sshPublicKey       
          by self write
          by dn="cn=Manager,dc=sample,dc=com" write             
          by anonymous auth
          by * none
```

I want to change the userPassword, shadowLastChange, description, sshPublicKey  by user(sysUsers). But its giving me permission error, Doesn't write permission.

```
# slapacl -D '' -b 'uid=user1,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com'
 authcDN: ""
 entry: read(=rscxd)
 children: read(=rscxd)
 gidNumber=1000: read(=rscxd)
 homeDirectory=/home/user1: read(=rscxd)
　　：
 cn=user1: read(=rscxd)
 sshPublicKey=ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza…cGWliPbw== root@sample.com: read(=rscxd)
 userPassword=****: read(=rscxd)
 description=test user1: read(=rscxd)
　　：
 modifyTimestamp=20161025074434Z: read(=rscxd)
```

```
LDAP reponse:   Insufficient access
error number:   0x32 (LDAP_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS)
description:    You do not have sufficient permissions to perform that operation.
```

I tried modifying description by user uid=user1,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com, but failed.

uid=Manager,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com is able to modify though.

what am I doing wrong? I suspect ACL problem?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> olcAccess: {0}to *      
>           by self write       
>           by dn="cn=Manager,dc=sample,dc=com" write       
>           by * read
> olcAccess: {1}to dn.children="ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com" 
>            attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange,description,sshPublicKey       
>           by self write
>           by dn="cn=Manager,dc=sample,dc=com" write             
>           by anonymous auth
>           by * none
> ```

First of all the ACL sequence you have given is not correct, In this case everything will be matched to first directive as it has "*" in , Which matches everything, and it will never go to the second rule of ACL.

Second, The command you have used to check the ACL permissions is incorrect, You have used:

> ```
> slapacl -D '' -b 'uid=user1,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com'
> ```

Which is incorrect -D is the DN **whose** permissions are to be checked and -b  is baseDN **to** which permissions is to be checked.

So correct command should be check self permissions:

```
slapacl -D 'uid=user1,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com' -b 'uid=user1,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com'
```

**EDIT AFTER YOUR FINDINGS**: The ACL you had applied was for **dn:olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config** whereas it should be applied for Database DN **dn:olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config**

What I am pretty sure you are trying to do is change the description of DN:"uid=Manager,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com" which ofcourse according to ACL any other won't be able to do except DN:"uid=Manager,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com" itself or DN:"cn=Manager,dc=sample,dc=com".

Hope this helps! Please support the answer by marking it as helped or answered if it did.

Answer (score 0):

to. Anirudh Malhotra
thanks replied.

i tried change ALC.

```
[root@evolable-ldap-01 cn=config]# cat olcDatabase\=\{0\}config.ldif
# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 57182ee5
dn: olcDatabase={0}config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
olcDatabase: {0}config
olcAddContentAcl: TRUE
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcMaxDerefDepth: 15
olcReadOnly: FALSE
olcRootDN: cn=config
olcSyncUseSubentry: FALSE
olcMonitoring: FALSE
structuralObjectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
entryUUID: af419f18-0036-1035-8ba5-452a6aebab7f
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20151006052730Z
olcAccess: {0}to dn.children="ou=sysUsers,dc=evolableasia,dc=net" 
          attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange,description,sshPublicKey
       by dn="uid=user1,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com" write
       by self write
       by dn="cn=Manager,dc=sample,dc=com" write
       by * none
olcAccess: {1}to *
       by self write
       by dn="cn=Manager,dc=sample,dc=com" write
       by anonymous auth
       by * read
entryCSN: 20161026004145.362887Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=manager,dc=sample,dc=com
modifyTimestamp: 20161026004145Z
```

But, slapacl is not changed.

```
# slapacl -D '' -b 'uid=user1,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com'
 authcDN: "uid=user1,ou=sysusers,dc=sample,dc=com"
 entry: read(=rscxd)
 children: read(=rscxd)
 gidNumber=1000: read(=rscxd)
 homeDirectory=/home/user1: read(=rscxd)
　　：
 cn=user1: read(=rscxd)
 sshPublicKey=ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza…cGWliPbw== root@sample.com: read(=rscxd)
 userPassword=****: read(=rscxd)
 description=test user1: read(=rscxd)
　　：
 modifyTimestamp=20161025074434Z: read(=rscxd)
```

Comment: I see you are new to stackexchange, Please use comments to ask counter queries. All the **answers** are written here. Now as far as your question is concerned, as I answered in my reply above You are using **slapacl -D '' -b 'uid=user1,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com'** to see user ACL which is **incorrect**. Instead correct usage is **slapacl -D 'uid=user1,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com' -b 'uid=user1,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com'**, Please post the output of this!

Comment: slapacl -D '' -b 'uid=user1,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com' and slapacl -D 'uid=user1,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com' -b 'uid=user1,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com'  result same except authcDN

Comment: Can you please update the **updated** output of both in question. Also I see you are editing your outputs. **Please** do not add anything, If you want to edit thats ok but do not add anything because that is going to stop us from getting to the bottom of this. Also your outputs of **slapacl -D '' -b 'uid=user1,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com'** in question and your answer above differ. That is why I am saying that do not edit(add anything) your answers, otherwise you will be left with no solution and I won't care!

Comment: # diff aaa.txt  bbb.txt
1c1
< authcDN: ""
---
> authcDN: "uid=user1,ou=sysusers,dc=sample,dc=com"

Comment: aaa.txt is slapacl -D '' -b 'uid=user1,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com'  and bbb.txt is slapacl -D 'uid=user1,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com' -b 'uid=user1,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com'

Comment: I think there is some language gap. I want output of "slapacl -D 'uid=user1,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com' -b 'uid=user1,ou=sysUsers,dc=sample,dc=com'" printed in the question. Can you do that? I can do a remote session to see whats happening if you dont have a problem otherwise this will go on and on.

Comment: i solved.  acl is olcDatabase={2}bdb.ldif file. i modified   olcDatabase={0}config.ldif so not applied. thanks.

Comment: Oh yeah :p missed that.

Comment: edited my answer please mark answered if it helped. Thanks!